# How to find a desktop window (by window name) in Windows 8.1 Update 2 OS, using the Win32 API FindWindow() in PowerShell environment?

Tags: windows, powershell

I don't remember having any problem finding a window in older Windows OS's, but, I'm not succeeding in Windows 8.1 Update 2 OS, using **PowerShell v4.0**.

This is the **PowerShell v4.0** code I'm using (pretty much trivial):

```
$sig=@'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);
'@

$fw = Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name Funcs -MemberDefinition $sig -PassThru
$wname='Form1' # any existing window name

$fw::FindWindow($null -as [String], $wname) # returns 0, always!
```

The last command returns **0**, always.

Changing the DllImport attribute to

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

does not change anything; **0** is returned the same way.

Interesting to notice that the equivalent code in **C#**, returns the correct **HWND** value.

Does anyone know what's wrong (and how to fix) the **PowerShell v4.0** code above?

Comment: Did you try FindWindowEx? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This one is for finding child windows. What's wrong with FindWindow()? It's used since long time ago (for top level windows) correctly. Inclusive, it works correctly in C# environment.

Comment: You can find toplevel windows as well. From the doc: "If hwndParent is NULL, the function uses the desktop window as the parent window. The function searches among windows that are child windows of the desktop." The reason I suggested it is that I found some articles (related to C++) also having trouble with FindWindow under Windows 8.1 and using FindWindowEx as a workaround.

Comment: Can you please post links to those C++ articles?

Comment: Just to be clear, FindWindowEx() does not work too, unfortunately. If you have those links, I'll appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Adding the window classname to the call seems to resolve the issue. Following works for me when trying to find notepad `$fw::FindWindowA('Notepad', $wname) # returns a handle.`. I traced `FindWindow` up into `ZwFindWindowEx` and can see the parameters being passed but it'll require some kernel debugging to know what happens next. My best guess is that the call into the kernel has changed.

Comment: I find a solution working for me changing the Pinvoke template to allow `[IntPtr]::Zero` as first parameter as advised in Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @zyq do you try it ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please, see my reply below your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First** :  not an answer but to help other people working on it, if you use the good class, for example here I code `CalcFrame` wich is the real class of the main window of `calc.exe` it works.

```
$fw::FindWindow("CalcFrame", $wname) # returns the right value for me if calc.exe is started.
```

**Second** : The following works for me ; accordind to [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) the first parameter should be null, but accordin to [PInvok](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow)e site *you must pass IntPtr.Zero as the first parameter*.

```
$sig = @"
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr sClassName, String sAppName);

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern uint GetLastError();
"@

$fw = Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name Funcs -MemberDefinition $sig -PassThru
$wname='Calculatrice' # any existing window name

$fw::FindWindow([IntPtr]::Zero, $wname ) # returns the Window Handle
$a = $fw::GetLastError()
$a
```

Comment: Yes, There are 2 WNDCLASS structures being used inside C# implementation, as I explain below.

Comment: I had a look at the C# implementation for this issue, and found 2 WNDCLASS structures: WNDCLASS_D AND WNDCLASS_I. The former is the traditional structure that uses strings as types, following the Win32 API. But the latter, uses IntPtr.Zero values for those WNDCLASS structure that take null string values. For this reason, specifying null string values will result in noting found because a null string value is not implicitly convertible to IntPtr.Zero.

Comment: "...Zero is equivalent to null for Windows API functions with parameters or return values that can be either pointers or null..." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.zero?view=net-7.0

Comment: "you must pass IntPtr.Zero as the first parameter" is nowhere to find on pinvoke now but it seems to be true, although it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the method doesn't fail if, and only if, the `ClassName` is also specified (cannot be `null`) like in this example:

```
$sig=@'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@    

$w32 = Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name Funcs -MemberDefinition $sig -PassThru
$w32::FindWindow('ConsoleWindowClass', 'Windows PowerShell') # Windows PowerShell Console
```

If the ClassName is `null`, then the JPBlanc's method works correctly, which specifies a different signature for the method.

Comment: It's not a "different signature for the method" from the Windows-API. It's just on the PowerShell side as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine for me, thanks to @zyq's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021198/1044966)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Test', 'PowerShell Dialog', 
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, 
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information, 
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton]::Button1,
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions]::ServiceNotification
        )

$Win32API = Add-Type -Name Funcs -Namespace Win32 -PassThru -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, IntPtr lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@

$Win32API::FindWindow('#32770',       'PowerShell Dialog')
$Win32API::FindWindow([IntPtr]::Zero, 'PowerShell Dialog')
$Win32API::FindWindow('#32770',       [IntPtr]::Zero)
$Win32API::FindWindow('Notepad',      [IntPtr]::Zero)
```

Comment: I have always wondered why passing Null always fails. It turns out that the declaration must include all types. Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the C# implementation for this issue, and found 2 WNDCLASS structures: WNDCLASS_D AND WNDCLASS_I. The former is the traditional structure that uses strings as types, following the Win32 API. But the latter, uses IntPtr.Zero values for those WNDCLASS structure that take null string values. For this reason, specifying null string values will result in noting found because a null string value is not implicitly convertible to IntPtr.Zero.

Comment: If you say so, no problem. I marked your reply as correct instead of mine.

Comment: It's as you want, but I just don't understand why you do not put your your answer as a comment of my one ?

Comment: It is there much before your reply above. Your answer is not an answer in your own words. Also, I posted my reply as additional  answer, because it tells why the code must use IntPtr.Zero and not just that it must use it. But I do appreciate your reply.

Comment: Many thanks, replacing $null with [IntPtr]::Zero works for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is trying to pass `$null` to a string-typed parameter, which results in an empty string instead. This means that `FindWindow` will search for an empty class name, which will never succeed.

This used to be a well-known limitation and has been the reason [NullString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.nullstring) was introduced (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353894) for more information).

Borrowing some code from Valdemar's answer, the following should work:

```
$Win32API = Add-Type -Name Funcs -Namespace Win32 -PassThru -MemberDefinition @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@

# find window by title only
$Win32API::FindWindow([NullString]::Value, 'window title')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have packaged it into a function for the convenience of use.

```
function Find-Window {
    <#
    .Synopsis
        user32dll.FindWindow(className, windowName)
    .Outputs
        @{
           Hwnd
           Err
        }
    .Example
        Find-Window 'ConsoleWindowClass' 'Windows PowerShell'
        Find-Window ApplicationFrameWindow 小算盤
        fWin 'ConsoleWindowClass' 'Windows PowerShell'
    .Example
        # class only
        Find-Window Notepad
    .Example
        # windowName only
        Find-Window -windowName Calculatrice
        Find-Window -windowName 小算盤
    #>
    [alias('fWin')]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$className = "",
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$windowName = ""
    )

    $sig=@'
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698671/9935654
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, IntPtr lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetLastError();
'@

    $w32 = Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name Funcs -MemberDefinition $sig -PassThru
    $cName = if ($className -eq "") {[IntPtr]::Zero} else {$className}
    $wName = if ($windowName -eq "") {[IntPtr]::Zero} else {$windowName}
    $r = $w32::FindWindow($cName, $wName)
    $o = @{
       Hwnd = 0
       Err = $null
    }
    if ($r -eq 0) {
        $o.Err = $w32::GetLastError()
        return $o
    }
    $o.Hwnd = $r
    return $o
}
```