# FindWindow in Powershell gives me 0 (on w11 22h2 FR) : unattended character in the title of a cmd elevated console?

Tags: windows, powershell, findwindow

8 years after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780138/how-to-find-a-desktop-window-by-window-name-in-windows-8-1-update-2-os-using) with Windows 11 22H2 FR, in Powershell PSVersion 5.1.22621.169
the command:

```
FindWindow("ConsoleWindowClass", "Administrateur : X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe")
```

outputs `0`.

After some rechearch, I use SPY++ for reading caption and class.
I have copy/pasted from the editbox of SpY++ into a PS string variable (`$title`).
And I notice in this copy/pasted `$title` string:

```
[byte]$title[14]= 160
```

`[byte]$title[14]` looks like a space and is here, in the middle "r :"
String index `14` is for french version of OS.

`FindWindow` returns a good handle with this character!

Question : Why `[byte]$title[14] = 160` (at index `14` in the string for FR) is found in the title of an elevated `cmd` console? Is it normal? Where is it documented?

The code I used:

```
$code = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string ClassName,string WindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ShowWindow( IntPtr hWnd, int  nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowText(IntPtr HWND, string Text);
'@
Add-Type  -MemberDefinition $code -Name Window -Namespace Test
# please, open an elevated console cmd
#Be carrefull, "administrateur" in french OS. So, adapt if you test...
# here,  "[byte]$title[14] = 32" -> it's a space, it's not 160
$name = "Administrateur : X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
$classW = "ConsoleWindowClass"
[Test.Window]::FindWindow($classW, $name)
#it gives 0
```

I don't know how to put a code point of `160` into a `system.string` (I can only copy/paste the title from SPY++). So I can't give the correct code for the second test.

**In summary:**

I launch a cmd console elevated and see the title:

```text
"Administrateur : X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
...............|..............................
```

The above line is for locating the position of the "strange" character with code point of `160`.

With PS, i try to use `FindWindow` to get a handle on this window
If I copy/paste the title from SPY++ (`[byte]$title[14] = 160`), `FindWindow` is OK.

If I enter the text from the keyboard (`[byte]$title[14] = 32`), `FindWindow` returns 0 (error).

Is it normal to get a title text with code point `160` (at index `14` in the string for FR)?

Comment: As an aside: Characters in .NET (and therefore also PowerShell) are Unicode code units, and therefore `[uint16]`-typed. Therefore, `[byte]` will only work for those characters whose code point happens to be `0` and `255`, and break with others; try `[uint16] [char] '€'` vs. `[byte] [char] '€'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unicode character whose code point is `160` (decimal) / `0xA0` (hexadecimal) is:

- (NO-BREAK SPACE, [`U+00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0))

It *looks* just like a space, but is obviously different from it.

To embed in a string, you have several options; the easiest is to use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) with either an embedded subexpression ([`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) or, in PowerShell (Core) 6+ only, a [Unicode escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters):

```bash
# Subexpression:
# Works in Windows PowerShell too.
"Administrateur$([char] 0xA0): X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"

# Unicode escape sequence: 
# Works in PowerShell (Core) 6+ only
"Administrateur`u{A0}: X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

---

As for ***why* this character is present**:

The original purpose of the character is to *prevent automatic line breaks* between words, which a regular space character wouldn't do - see Wikipedia's article on the [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Given that window titles are always *single-line*, that alone cannot be the reason for the character's use.

With English or German as the system language, for instance, the character is *not* present: there's simply *no* character between the (localized) word for administrator and `:`

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) observes the following with respect to why the character is present *in French*, for instance:

- In French (and possibly other languages), `:` (and other punctuation) must be preceded by a (non-breaking) space - see [What’s The Deal With French Spacing?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)
- In *general*, it makes sense to use a no-break space between `:` and the word that precedes it, so as not have a "dangling" `:` on a new line.
- *Possibly*, there is *shared code* that inserts the no-break space before `:` for text localized to French, so that it just happens to surface in this context too.

Pragmatically speaking:

- The behavior is obscure with respect to *finding* windows running elevated sessions by title.
- With respect to *parsing* such a title (once found), splitting into the part before and after the `:` actually then works the same in *all* languages, but only if you split by *regular spaces only*, such as with 
  `"Administrateur$([char] 0xA0): X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" -split ' '` (by contrast, `-split "Administrateur$([char] 0xA0): X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"` *would* split by the no-break space too).

---

As for **how to *diagnose* the problem *programmatically***:

```bash
(Get-Process -Name cmd | Where-Object MainWindowTitle -Match '^Administr').MainWindowTitle | 
  ForEach-Object ToCharArray |
  ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{ Char = $_; CodePoint = '0x{0:x}' -f ([uint16] $_) }
  }
```

The above prints each character alongside its Unicode code point on its own line.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648684/45375) shows convenience function `Debug-String`, which greatly simplifies examining strings for unexpected characters.

Comment: FR as i said.So, it's a normal code put by MS when he build the text of the title. The method to write the string is good.Thank you very much

Comment: @zett42 French non-breaking space will be for me like interstellar space. I thought I knew my mother tongue but at 66, I'm still learning a lot with you. Really thank you.

Comment: it is for me a beautiful lesson of writing in PS. Really thank you.